# How to skip the first 2 frames?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, frame

Hi I have a while(1) which does a infinite loop, is there a way to ignore the first 2 frames?

```
while(1)
{
    bool bSuccess = capture.read(fullimage); // read a new frame from video

    if (!bSuccess)                          //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "End of video" << endl;
        destroyWindow("Original Video");
        destroyWindow("dctBlockImage");
        break;
    }

    imshow("Original Video", fullimage);    //show the frame in "Original Video" window

    FrameTo8by8(myinput,3.0);               //Proccess and algorithm

    oVideoWriter.write(dctImage);           //write video to file

    namedWindow("dctBlockImage"); 
    imshow("dctBlockImage", dctImage);      //display watermarked image


    if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
    {
        cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl; 
        break; 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to skip the first 2 frames?

Comment: `capture.read(blah); capture.read(blah); while(true) { ... }`?

Comment: @BoBTFish thanks for the comment. So i need to repeat capture.read() twice and change while(1) to while(true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as mentioned in the comment:

```
capture.read(blah);
capture.read(blah);
while(true) { ... }
```

or you can add a counter and use it for skipping the frames that you want like this:

```
std::size_t cntr = 0;
while (true)
{
  // ...
  if (cntr < 2) // here you can add any condition you need
  {
    cntr++; // You can also put this where you need it; I have put it here not to increment if not needed
    continue;
  }
}
```

But I think that for your purpose is better to use BoBTFish's version.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of video file you can use [VideoCapture::set](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) to set the index of the frame to be captured next, where you could use the macro `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` to set the index. You should use this before entering to while() loop.